# Difference between assignment of a variable to a number and lists of numbers in Python

Tags: python

In python if assign a list of numbers to a variable in the following way

```
>>>a=range(4)
>>>b=a
>>>a[2]=9
>>>b
[0,1,9,3]
```

but when I assign a single variable in a similar way I get the following result

```
>>>a=1
>>>b=a
>>>a=2
>>>b
1
```

Why is it that b=1 instead of b=2 as in the result from assigning the variable to a list?

Comment: Because integers are immutable and lists are mutable.

Comment: I was going to write something much wordier, but @jonrsharpe explained it much more concisely.

Comment: For more detail/examples, check out http://stackoverflow.com/a/8059504/1819790

Comment: What other types are mutable/immutable?

Comment: @Anode you can read about the built-in types in [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html). You might also find [this](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html) useful.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Isn't explaining the output solely with mutability a little misleading here? Even if integers were mutable, the second code snippet would lead to two names, `a` and `b`, pointing to different integer objects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your first example, `a` and `b` are both references to the same object, a list. When you change the list, so does the output for `a` and `b` (which still point to the same list).
In your second example, you are assigning a **new** integer object to the name `a`. `a` and `b` are two different objects with different ids now. Demo:

```
>>> a = range(4)
>>> b = a
>>> id(a)
38845472
>>> id(b)
38845472
>>> a=1
>>> b=a
>>> id(a)
33619048
>>> id(b)
33619048
>>> b=2
>>> id(a)
33619048
>>> id(b)
33619024
```

Answer (score -2):

Integers are *immutable* so to speak, that you can not change them with slicing, unlike lists:

```
>>> x = range(4)
>>> x
[0, 1, 2, 3]
>>> id(x)
4300734408
>>> x[0] = 5
>>> id(x)
4300734408
>>> x = 1
>>> id(x)
4299162584
>>> x+=1
>>> id(x)
4299162560
>>>
```

As you can see above, you can change the list, but it still has the same `id`. However, if you call `+=` on an integer, the `id` changes.

This is exactly why although you change `a`, `b` doesn't change along with it.

Comment: Your example is completely irrelevant to the topic of mutable/immutable.